# Angular Error : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $urlRouteProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get an angular error : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $urlRouteProvider

I am using ui-router for routing

My Html Code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="container">
        <header ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></header>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
    </div>


</body>
```

My Module:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router'])
    .config(["$urlRouteProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouteProvider, $stateProvider) {
            $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/index.html');

            $stateProvider.state("home", {
                url: '/',
                template: "home"
            });
        }]);
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: It's `$urlRouterProvider`, with an R :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add ui router scripts to the index html file.

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
 <script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Then there is character missing in here also.

change `$urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/index.html');`

```
.config(["$urlRouteProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouteProvider, $stateProvider)
```

to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index.html');`

```
.config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider)
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ilNBJKOylXSOxhtJUG3f?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Mate !! Worked.

Comment: @punith gowda no prob bro make sure to mark is as right answer if this helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve your dependencies on other modules, for your module to work.

So rearrange your code to

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js" defer></script>
    <script src="Controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
       <div class="container">
           <header ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></header>
           <div ui-view></div>
           <footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
      </div>
 </body>
```

And also change your dependency name from **$urlRouteProvider** to **$urlRouterProvider**

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router'])
   .config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the controller.js after loading ui router reference

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js" defer></script>
 <script src="Controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also change from

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router'])
    .config(["$urlRouteProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouteProvider, $stateProvider) {
```

to

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router'])
    .config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
```